# Do Makefiles use environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, command-line

I want to use a environment variable in my Makefile which looks like that:

```
.PHONY: stuff

stuff:
    @echo $(AWS_PROFILE)
```

Expected behavior after I set the variable:

```sh
$ export AWS_PROFILE=beta
$ echo $AWS_PROFILE
beta
$ make stuff
beta
$
```

actual behavior:

```sh
$ export AWS_PROFILE=beta
$ echo $AWS_PROFILE
beta
$ make stuff

$
```

I thought that makefiles can use exported variables...

Comment: It works for me as expected.

Comment: @frathert : What `make` are you using? Do you also have a a make variable of the same name (in which you likely have to use `-e` in order to give precedence for your environment variable).

Comment: @user1934428 I am using GNU Make 3.81 and no there is no other variable of the same name. I tried with `-e` but it didn't work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell : It seems to me from what the OP pasted in his question, that the `@echo` is executed; it just seems to print an empty line.

Comment: @user1934428 You are almost certainly right, I'll delete it. Thank you.

Comment: @frathert : Can not reproduce with GNU make 4.3: If I run the makefile which you posted (I have for the safe side inserted a second `@echo xxxx`, just to verify that the target is executed) with `AWS_PROFILE=testing make stuff`, I can see that _make_  correctly outputs _testing_.

Comment: Can you try `@echo $$AWS_PROFILE` ?

Comment: @Philippe I tried but it didn't change. it worken with `AWS_PROFILE=beta make stuff` but not when I export the variable and then run make.

Comment: That is very strange. They are supposed to have exactly same behaviour.

Comment: There is no way that the situation as you've laid it out here can cause the results you see.  Therefore, there must be something about your setup or environment that is other from what you describe here, that's causing your problem.  I can't guess at what that might be, unless your `make` is really an alias or shell script that clears your environment or something.  I can't remember any bug in GNU make 3.81 that might cause this.  I guess you could try a newer version.